# Changing Android's (5.0>) EditText error background color

Tags: android, android-layout

I searched everywhere without success. 
Looking at source code, the 'magic' is done in class android.widget.Editor (marked as @hide) when in method showError():

```
final TextView err = (TextView) inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.textview_hint, null);
```

And in textview_hint.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"/>
```

The thing is that I cant extend Editor (because it's marked as @hide) and I just didn't figure out another way to override the setting

How could changing background color and textcolor styles for error messsage  be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean the color of the popup containing the error text?

Comment: *How could changing this styles be achieved?* Which style?

Comment: Yes, background color and textcolor, sorry, it says in the title, but I editted the text to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy if you use the new [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) from the new [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). All you need to do is wrap the EditText in the TextInputLayout and set the text appearance for the error message (and hint) there.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/CustomErrorStyle"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/CustomHintStyle">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/full_size_hint_color"
    android:hint="Hint" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```